# GitLab CI - Cannot connect to the Docker daemon from within an image

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, alpine-linux

I have a node-based project and following are the first few steps that are required to be executed as part of the build:

```
npm install
npm run build
docker build -t client .
```

The last command above builds the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.artifactory.abc.net/nginx
COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Content of `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: docker.artifactory.abc.net/docker/node:1.0

stages:
   - build
   - deploy

build:
   stage: build
   script:
   - npm install
   - npm run build
   - docker build -t client .
```

In the above Dockerfile, i am using a custom node image (`node:1.0`) which contains the proxy settings for `apk` to work and Artifactory configuration so all the dependencies are fetched using Artifactory. Now when i was running this build, i was getting `docker: command not found` error while executing the last command (`docker build -t client .`), which is expected because the base image is for `node` and doesn't contain `docker`. So i added docker setup instructions to the node Dockerfile based on [this](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/a6b52c73daa8283cd861f41f55e53426008708ac/17.09/Dockerfile) link except for the last 3 lines where it's configuring the ENTRYPOINT and CMD.

Now when i ran the build, i got:

```
$ docker build -t client .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  372.7MB

Step 1 : FROM docker.artifactory.abc.net/nginx
Get https://docker.artifactory.abc.net/v2/nginx/manifests/latest: unknown: Authentication is required
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

This error, as per my past experience, had to do with running `docker login` command. Since the docker setup in [official image](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/a6b52c73daa8283cd861f41f55e53426008708ac/17.09/Dockerfile) uses tar, i had to add `docker` user to `/etc/group` and then add current user (root) to the `docker` group. Also added the `docker login` command as shown below to the Dockerfile:

```
    addgroup docker; \
    adduser root docker; \
    docker login docker.artifactory.abc.net -u svc-art -p "ZTg6#&kq"; \
```

After that, if i try building this Dockerfile, i get following error:

```
+ dockerd -v
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build v17.05.0-ce
+ docker -v
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build v17.05.0-ce
+ adduser root docker
+ tail -2 /etc/group
node:x:1000:node
docker:x:101:root
+ docker login docker.artifactory.abc.net -u svc-art -p ZTg6#&kq
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I also did an `ls -ltr /var/run/docker.sock;` and the docker socket file was not present *inside* the image. This seems to be the issue.

Any idea how i can get this working?

Comment: Its hard to follow exactly what is happening. But I think the problem is docker is not found on your host machine, not the docker container. The build("docker build" command) is being run on your host and that's where its not found. As to the "Cannot connect to the Docker Daemon" error, that's something I've experienced and fixed it [this way](http://mbacchi.github.io/2017/09/28/docker-socket-group-permission.html)

Comment: So i guess, i wasn't too clear in my post. Let me try now. Docker is indeed running on my host and that's the reason why the image (`node:1.0`) mentioned in the first line of `.gitlab-ci.yml` is working fine as i am using docker socket method in GitLab CI runner. The issue is when this image itself has to run some docker command _within itself_ i.e., within the node image, it fails because docker doesn't seem to be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from the example you have provided I cannot see where you call your docker service, therefore I assume you are not calling it also you are not logging into the registry.

The way your pipeline should look like is something as follows:

```
 image: docker.artifactory.abc.net/docker/node:1.0

 stages:
    - build
    - deploy

 build:
   image: docker:latest
   services:
   - docker:dind
   stage: build
   script:
     - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.example.com
     - docker build -t registry.example.com/group/project/image:latest .
     - docker push registry.example.com/group/project/image:latest
```

You could also find more info [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html)

Comment: Thanks a ton @Sergiu! I wasn't using `docker login` within the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. In retrospect, i was thinking why this didn't strike me especially when i'd already seen such examples before. :( Was unnecessarily thinking it in a complex way. Thanks again! :)

Comment: You're more than welcome :) I came across this problems most of the time, that's when I was reading your question it strike me that you might have forgotten or to login or to use the DIND service :) But glad that I could help.

Comment: Ok. :) Just for records, i tried DIND earlier but couldn't get it working so currently i am using Docker socket method. Will again give a try to DIND sometime later. In the current issue, i was actually trying to put the `docker login` command _inside_ of `docker.artifactory.abc.net/docker/node:1.0` image. Not sure why it was not working although i installed Docker using it's tar file as described [here](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/a6b52c73daa8283cd861f41f55e53426008708ac/17.09/Dockerfile). Anyways, at least i have a working build now. :)